# Excel dynamic static data issue when using CopyFromRecordset rs VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns A through to column E being populated via the statement `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset rs`. It pulls data from an Access database.

Columns F through to L hold information that is manually entered into the workbook for each record.

**Issue **

If a new record is added it appears fine in column A. It also appears in the right order however any information that was against the previous record in the same row hasn't moved hence it is no longer accurate.

For example prior to a new record being added in the Access database record `ABC` appeared in row 16 in Excel. When a new record is added e.g `AAA` it now  appears in row 16 and `ABC` appears in row 17. Any information in columns F to H at row 16 hasn't moved a row down and is now against `AAA`.

Comment: If you want to keep the records lined up then you'll need to do a bit more work in your code: check the id from each record against the existing data in the sheet and copy the values to the appropriate row.  If the id isn't found on the sheet then add a new row.

Comment: @Tim Williams - Is there an example i could follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim f as range, id, sht as worksheet

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

do while not rs.eof

    id =  rs.Fields("idField").Value  'unique id for this record
    'already listed ?
    Set f = sht.columns(1).find(what:=id, lookin:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    if f is nothing then 'not listed: add to sheet
       set f = sht.cells(rows.count,1).End(xlUp).offset(1,0)
       f.Value = id
    end if

    'fill in/update rest of values
    With f.entirerow
        .cells(2).value = rs.Fields("field2").Value
        .cells(3).value = rs.Fields("field3").Value
        'etc
    end with

    rs.movenext
loop
```

Comment: Thanks. When you say ID, what ID are you referring to as there is no static table or column that can be referenced?

Comment: To do this at all, you will need a way of identifying a unique row in your recordset so that you can match that against the Excel sheet data. Otherwise, how will you know if a new record has been added (or an existing one updated) ?

Comment: Thanks. I do agree. I was hoping there would be another way. In column 1 i have the name of the records from the database and in column 14 i have a reference for each record that is manually added e.g Columns 1 to 5 are dynamic whilst Columns 7 to 14 are static however even doing so, the rows don't move or shift.